# How to send JSON and an Image in same POST request and cascade it? Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I have an entity called "Bga" which has a list of Images. I'm trying to create a Bga sending its data via JSON and in the same request i want to upload an Image, so i can cascade it **and the table "Image" in database will have the foreign key comming from Bga and Bga will have its list of images**.

What i'm doing:

Sending a multipart form:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b3kQd.png)

Which has the JSON data from the entity Bga:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dYTGU.png)

And the second entry is the image that i uploaded

I can create a Bga and upload an Image separately, but i don't know how to do it in a way that i can cascade it.

**The POST request**:

```
@PostMapping
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<Bga> createBga(@RequestPart("bga") Bga bga, @RequestPart("file") MultipartFile file) throws IOException {

        fileStorage.save(file);

        bgaRepository.save(bga);

        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body(bga);
    }
```

**And then the service which uploads an image**:

```
@Service
public class FileStorageService {
    
    @Autowired
    private ImagemRepository imagemRepository;

public Imagem save(MultipartFile file) throws IOException {
        String fileName = StringUtils.cleanPath(file.getOriginalFilename());
        Imagem Imagem = new Imagem(fileName, file.getContentType(), file.getBytes());

        return imagemRepository.save(Imagem);
    }

}
```

**I'm using JPA repository for both**

Entity Bga:

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;


@Entity
@Table(name="BGA")
public class Bga implements Serializable {
    
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id_bga;
    
    
    private String nome;
    
    private int num_bga;
    

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "bga", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Imagem> imagens;
    
    public Bga() {
        
    }


    

    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    public int getNum_bga() {
        return num_bga;
    }

    public void setNum_bga(int num_bga) {
        this.num_bga = num_bga;
    }

    public long getId_bga() {
        return id_bga;
    }

    public void setId_bga(long id_bga) {
        this.id_bga = id_bga;
    }

    public List<Imagem> getImagens() {
        return imagens;
    }

    public void setImagens(List<Imagem> imagens) {
        this.imagens = imagens;
    }
```

And entity Image:

```
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.Lob;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;


@Entity
public class Imagem {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id_imagem;

    private String name;

    private String type;

    @Lob
    private byte[] imagem;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_bga", referencedColumnName = "id_bga")
    private Bga bga;

public Imagem() {

    }
    
    public Long getId_imagem() {
        return id_imagem;
    }

    public void setId_imagem(Long id_imagem) {
        this.id_imagem = id_imagem;
    }

    public byte[] getImagem() {
        return imagem;
    }

    public void setImagem(byte[] imagem) {
        this.imagem = imagem;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public Imagem(String name, String type, byte[] imagem) {
        this.name = name;
        this.type = type;
        this.imagem = imagem;
    }

    public Bga getBga() {
        return bga;
    }

    public void setBga(Bga bga) {
        this.bga = bga;
    }
```

**But the way i'm doing Bga doesn't get the uploaded image**:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fJKpJ.png)

**How to do it in a way that i can cascade it, so the table Image will have a foreign key comming from bga?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be careful about transaction boundaries. You want 1 transaction to store a file + BGA, so:

1. Create a @Service with a transactional method which takes a file and a bga
2. Autowire the FileStorageService and the BgaRepository into the service
3. Run `fileStorage.save(file)` and `bgaRepository.save(bga)` in that method, then set bga on the Imagem

Extend your FileStorageService to also take a Bga object:

```
@Service
public class FileStorageService {

    @Autowired
    private ImagemRepository imagemRepository;
    @Autowired // NEW
    private BgaRepository bgaRepository; // NEW

    @Transactional // NEW
    public Imagem save(Bga bga, MultipartFile file) throws IOException {
        String fileName = StringUtils.cleanPath(file.getOriginalFilename());
        Imagem Imagem = new Imagem(fileName, file.getContentType(), file.getBytes());

        bgaRepository.save(bga); // NEW
        Imagem.setBga(bga); // NEW

        return imagemRepository.save(Imagem);
    }
}
```

and in your controller, only call 1 service with both DTOs:

```
@PostMapping
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<Bga> createBga(@RequestPart("bga") Bga bga, @RequestPart("file") MultipartFile file) throws IOException {

    fileStorage.save(bga, file); // NEW: passing in 'bga' here

    // bgaRepository.save(bga); .. DELETED

    return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body(bga);
}
```

Comment: Could you show me how its done, please? I've never heard of "transactional method", i'm kinda new to Spring Boot.

Comment: @werliney, I've edited my answer with a code example